# Изменение размера панели пользователем

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, грубо говоря, есть JFramе, на котором размещены две панели JPanel:

```
JFrame.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, panel1);
```

и

```
JFrame.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel2);
```

Нужно, чтобы пользователь мог линией пересечения между панелями изменять размеры панелей, двигая линию верх или вниз. Надеюсь, вы поняли, что я имею в виду. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Все ок, нашел ответ. Вопрос закрыт. )

Надо использовать Split Panes.

Если кому интересно, вот ссылочка:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html

Comment: А я через BoxLayout делал. Вот [тут][1] описал процесс.


  [1]: http://blog.dimka3210.ru/2014/11/java-jpanel-boxlayout.html